# Needs suggestions on CSS Grid design

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

There is some design change for the following `HTML` code. I Need to have similar UI in `CSS` grid design.

Any suggestions are welcomed

```html
<h3><Span style= 'color:red;'>***Remember SAIL while Reading email ***</Span></h3>
        <table style="border: 1px solid;">
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><span style='color:red;'>S</span>ender</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">sender of the email is  and friendly name is</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2">sample text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

How the above code can be changed to `CSS3` grid design.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! This isn't really the place to be asking this sort of question. StackOverflow is for questions about issues with code. The best thing you can do is Google around a bit and see if you can find some resources on CSS grid. You can take a look at the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), for example. If you have issues with this later on, come back here and we'll try to fix them. For future reference, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can create you table in following way. hope this will be useful.

```css
.grid-container{
 border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.grid-row:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.grid-container .col-2-8{
 grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}
.grid-container .col-10{
 grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.grid-item:last-child{
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3><Span style= 'color:red;'>***Remember SAIL while Reading email ***</Span></h3>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-row col-2-8">
      <div class="grid-item"><span style='color:red;'>S</span>ender</div>
      <div class="grid-item">sender of the email is and friendly name is</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row col-10">
      <div class="grid-item">sample text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```